# How to replace a array value inside a foreach loop in copy activity of ADF V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I use something like this to replace a string in the copy activity which is inside foreach loop. But i am facing issue in replacing the content. I am trying to pass file name as parameter. Please let me know what I am missing. Thanks!

```
replace(@item().SourceFiles,'Write','View')
```

Comment: it's not supported for now.

Comment: Can you please provide more details for us? what's the Foreach items?